# Errors of gitlab-8.16.3 on kubernetes

Tags: nginx, gitlab, kubernetes

When I setting up a gitlab-8.16.3 on k8s , two errors were appeared :

1.The gitlab-svc is always in the staus 'pending' but I can visit the gitlab by http://192.168.XXX.XXX:port . It is strange that the root user cannot login with user 'root' and password 'root' when I had set them in the gitlab-deployment.yml;

2.The nginx-ingress-lb pods give an error like :

`setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, 131072) failed (1: Operation not permitted)` ,

but I had update the ulimit with the local host . It's the result when I print in the "ulimit -n" command :

`ulimit -n
180000`

who can help me ? Thanks!

Comment: Now I notice that the ulimit is 65536 when I run the command 'ulimit -n' in the nginx-ingress-lb containers . Is the problem there ? How can I resolve it ?

Answer (score 1):

A service in `Pending` state normally indicates that a service of type `LoadBalancer` was used. A `LoadBalancer` service only works when using cloud providers like AWS, GCE, Azure, ...

This is only needed if you want to publicly expose the service with a public IP.

The `Pending` state is shown because Kubernetes waits forever for a load balancer to be set up and a public IP to be reported, which will never happen if you are not in one of the supported clouds.

As you seem to access the service with an internal IP instead of a public IP, I'd assume you actually don't want to expose it to the public. In that case, using a service of type `NodePort` is all you need. Please read https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#type-nodeport

I'm not sure about the ulimit error, but I'd assume it's not related to the problems you are facing.

The problems with the root login is not related as well. I don't have enough information about your setup and deployment to help here.

Comment: Thanks for your help . Hmmmm... , I think I should read the k8s document carefully now . Before that , I must resolve the second problem . Thank you again !